# Order (records) should always be completed in the order they were created

Tags: sql

For simplifying my question, I use a simple Orders table.

Orders are created during the day. Orders should be completed in the order they were created. So, it is not allowed to complete a smaller order before an older one.

So, simulating my real problem, I have an `ORDERS` table with these columns:

```
id: number
task: varchar
creation: DateTime
completed: DateTime
```

On creation, the `creation` column is filled and the `completed` column is null. When the order is completed, the `completed` column is filled with the current datetime.

How can I check with SQL that each order is processed in the order of creation? So, there may be no order completed that was created later.

To provide even more detail, the 3rd entry is invalid:

```
1 | task 1 | 08-04-2023 12:00:00 |  08-04-2023 15:00:00
2 | task 2 | 08-04-2023 13:00:00 |  08-04-2023 16:00:00
3 | task 3 | 08-04-2023 14:00:00 |  08-04-2023 15:50:00 <== should be after 16:00
4 | task 4 | 08-04-2023 15:00:00 |  08-04-2023 17:00:00
```

This could be programmed by fetching route by row with e.g. PL/SQL or similar, but it would help to get an SQL query.

@markalex, thank you for showing me the right direction.

EDIT: An alternative solution is:

```
select * from ORDERS 
where id in ( select o.id from ORDERS o, ORDERS o2
where ( o.creation> o2.creationand and o2.completed > o.completed));
```

Comment: Why not use `ORDER BY creation ASC`?

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to find rows violating described policy, use exists:

```sql
select *
from ORDER o
where exists (select 1
              from ORDER o2
              where o.id <> o2.id
              and o.completed between o2.creation and o2.completed)
```

Here you select orders, for which exists another order with completion timestamp of current order being between creation and completion of another.

And if you want to see both rows, use this:

```sql
select *
from ORDER o
join ORDER o2 on(o.id <> o2.id
                and o.completed between o2.creation and o2.completed);
```

Comment: I think 'NOT' is missing before the 'exists'. So: select *
from ltmr_mutatie_requests o
where not exists (select 1
              from ltmr_mutatie_requests o2
              where o.ltmr_mutatie_id <> o2.ltmr_mutatie_id
              and ( o.ltmr_verwerkt_tijdstip between o2.ltmr_aanmaak_tijdstip and o2.ltmr_verwerkt_tijdstip));

Comment: @tm1701, two queries from answer should show erroneous row, as I intended. I assumed by check you meant "find row that violate the rule". With `not exists` you'll get only "correct" ones.

Comment: No prob. You put me on the right track. Thank you very much! I +1 + v. You may be right, as I am trying these queries 'not exists' works in MySql and H2.